# How can I scan a document without losing the original quality?

Tags: fonts, scanner, scanning, document-scanning

I am scanning in pages from an old book so that I can recreate the font of this book, but the letters are pretty small and if I scan them in at 150 or 300 dpi I won't get the details needed to recreate this font, and a higher dpi with more details will be too large and my computer will crash.

So 1: How were books scanned and reprinted in (let's say) the 80's, that the prints have not lost quality with scanning (sure the letters are a bit smudged, but they aren't low resolution). So if I need to scan and retain the original quality, that seems to be my best shot, but how is that done?

And 2: Is there any technique in what to scan so that I won't (or just slightly) reduce the quality of the original pages?

REMEMBER, I am not scanning in a doc just to have it digitized, I need the full quality so that I can reconstruct a font from letters that are very small!!!

Comment: Sounds like your crashing computer is the main issue here - it shouldn't really have an issue with an A4-ish 600 dpi scan. What software are you using?

I usually scan at 600 dpi for decent quality.

Comment: I have Windows fax and scan and Readiris. when I refer to my computer crashing I was really referring to the software (Readiris) telling me that I don't have enough memory to scan the pages at such a high dpi. I scan it in as high dpi as possible so that when it comes to converting the raster (in my case .tif) to vector, it will need as least work as possible and be as true to the original as possible.
the pages are 9x6 and the letters are probably 9 or 10 pts.

Comment: Use another scan software, if Readiris is problematic. Your scanner should have come with such software, or it may be found on the website of its manufacturer. Most image editors also have the capability for capturing a scan.

Answer (score -2):

You're looking for Optical Character Recognition (OCR) software. This is the process of converting an image into machine encoded text. There are many different software solutions for this, many of which are free. Once you have the machine encoded text, you can edit it as you please.

150 and certainly 300DPI should suffise quality wise.

If its just the specific font that is important, try and have some software or service (like https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/ recognize it. Again,  there are plenty of those available with a quick google search

Comment: Digitizing a font from an old book is not OCR. Also it's unlikely that an old book font will match something digital.

Comment: He asked how books are scanned and reprinted. OCR is the most likely candidate, far more likely then scan/print. This also doesnt reduce the quality, his second question. If he wants a 100% identical font from the book, he's going to have to do it by hand. Lastly, the font should be identified in the books colophon and can likely be identified with a tool. What makes you think a printed font from say the 80's isnt currently digitized ?

Comment: in my question I asked about how books were reprinted in yesteryear, I asking about OCR, I wanted to know how they were reprinted in their original form, for that I found an answer, as stated in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facsimile) "In the past, techniques and devices such as the philograph (tracing an original through a transparent plane), photostat, hectograph, or lithograph were used to create facsimiles", I was asking that because they have seemed to not be reduced by the quality and easier to trace.
my apologies for the delayed response!

Comment: now looking back, both questions are really the same, the first question was "how was it done back then, that seems to do the job I'm looking for?" and part 2 "is there a mother way I can get it done"? I'll have to figure out how to write it clearer!